# Filling the space between bars in a bar graph made with Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I have a plotly bar graph.  The measurements illustrated by the graph are not directly adjacent; there is space between them.  I'd like to fill the space between measurements, making them the same value as the previous measurement.  Is this possible with plotly?

Edit for clarification: Let's say I have these measurements: [ 20=3, 25=3, 27=3, 30=10, 31=10, 50=2, 56=2 ] -- I'd want data points 20, 25, and 27 to appear as one big bar on the bar graph (filling the space on the x-axis between 20 and 27), 30 and 31, to be the same bar, and 50 and 56 to be the same bar.  The reason I want this is that I have millions of empty points in the graph, and if I fill them all manually, the graph grinds the browser to a halt.

Comment: I guess the answer is **yes**. Maybe use `width=...`?!

Comment: @jojo - I appreciate your curt assumption and attempt at help.  I've made an edit above to better illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possibilities would be to create a scatter plot for your measurements and add the bars as `shapes`. The simpler solution using `connectgaps: False` and `fill: tozeroy` doesn't work here.

```
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
import plotly.graph_objs as go

meas_x = [20, 25, 27, 30, 31, 50, 56]
meas_y = [3, 3, 3, 10, 10, 2, 2]
meas_y.append('None')
meas_x.append('None')

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=meas_x,
    y=meas_y,
    mode='markers'
)

shapes = list()    
y = meas_y[0]
x = meas_x[0]
for i, m_y in enumerate(meas_y[1:]):
    if y != m_y:
        shapes.append({
            'type': 'rect',
            'x0': x,
            'y0': 0,
            'x1': meas_x[i],
            'y1': meas_y[i - 1],
            'fillcolor': '#d3d3d3',
        })
        y = m_y
        x = meas_x[i + 1]

fig = {
    'data': [trace1],
    'layout': go.Layout(shapes=shapes)
}
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

[image: bars]

Comment: I copied your example, but the black lines (shapes) don't show up.  Only the blue markers.  Why might this be?

Comment: @horse hair: let me check, perhaps it was a copy&paste mistake

Comment: Just tried it again, copied the whole code to a new Jupyter notebook and it worked. What environment are you using?